# Which is the Correct way to user ActivityManager to get top Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-launcher

My custom launcher uses the following code to identify the top activity, and I compare with some allowed apps to run.

```
private void restoreApp() {
    ctx = this;
    am = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
      activePackages = getActivePackages();
    } else {
      activePackages = getActivePackagesCompat();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "restoreApp() -> ");
    Boolean testPackage  = false;
    if (activePackages != null) {
      for (String activePackage : activePackages) {
        Log.i(TAG, "testing  -> "+activePackage);
        if(!activePackage.contains("com.estapar.mobile.launcher")){
          if (allowedApps.testApp(activePackage)) {
            restoreAppExec(activePackage);
            testPackage = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "restoring  -> "+activePackage);
          }
        }
      }
      if(!testPackage){
        restoreAppExec("launcher");
      }
    }
    else{
      Log.i(TAG, "activePackages eh nulo");
    }
  }

  String[] getActivePackagesCompat() {
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    final ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    final String[] activePackages = new String[1];
    activePackages[0] = componentName.getPackageName();
    return activePackages;
  }

  String[] getActivePackages() {
    final Set<String> activePackages = new HashSet<String>();
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

    String mpackageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    String mPackageName2 = am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;

    Log.i("asd",mpackageName);
    Log.i("asd",mPackageName2);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : processInfos) {
      if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
        activePackages.addAll(Arrays.asList(processInfo.pkgList));
      }
    }
    return activePackages.toArray(new String[activePackages.size()]);
  }
```

but in the Android version 5.1.1 it stop working =(, always returning the launcher package.

Does any one knows the correct way to use this approach in this android version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible anymore, as per android documentation

> This method was deprecated in API level 21. As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still retu rn a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FrankMonza, any idea how to workaround it?

Comment: There is no workaround unfortunately, you can try parsing PS output from shell but its probably not going to take you anywhere